# How avoid statefulWidget to dispose when switching pages?

Tags: flutter

I'm building an one page app. I'm use a Row to separate the page. On the left side I use NavigationRail to construct a menu icon panel to switch contents, and the content is on the right side of the Row. Contents are all construct with statefulWidgets.

I've notice that after I switch content, when I switch back, the content's has been disposed.

Is there a way other than navigator.push to avoid state dispose when a statefulwidget is not displaying?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class name extends StatefulWidget {
  name({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<name> createState() => _nameState();
}

class _nameState extends State<name> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        NavigationRail(
          onDestinationSelected: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = value;
            });
          },
          destinations: [
            NavigationRailDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: Text('0')),
            NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit), label: Text('1')),
          ],
          selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        ),
        Builder(builder: (content) {
          switch (_selectedIndex) {
            case 0:
              return testcontent();

            default:
              return Container();
          }
        }),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class testcontent extends StatefulWidget {
  testcontent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<testcontent> createState() => _testcontentState();
}

class _testcontentState extends State<testcontent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Expanded(child: TextFormField()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I've updated the question. But the problem is solved.
I managed to achieve by using ````Offstage```` widget. And there was also a deleted answer below suggested to use ````IndexedStack````, which is more elegant than using ````Offstage````.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out using `Offstage` widget can achieve the goal.
And there's also a deleted answer suggested `IndexedStack` widget, which is an more elegant way than `Offstage`.

I would like to select the IndexedStack for correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`PageStorage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageStorage-class.html)

> Establish a subtree in which widgets can opt into persisting states after being destroyed.

According to docs:

`PageStorage` is used to save and restore values that can outlive the widget. For example, when multiple pages are grouped in tabs, when a page is switched out, its widget is destroyed and its state is lost. By adding a `PageStorage` at the root and adding a `PageStorageKey` to each page, some of the page's state (e.g. the scroll position of a Scrollable widget) will be stored automatically in its closest ancestor PageStorage, and restored when it's switched back.

---

```
class Name extends StatefulWidget {
  Name({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NameState createState() => _NameState();
}

class _NameState extends State<Name> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageStorage(
      bucket: PageStorageBucket(), // create a new storage bucket
      child: Row(
        children: [
          NavigationRail(
            onDestinationSelected: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = value;
              });
            },
            destinations: [
              NavigationRailDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: Text('0')),
              NavigationRailDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit), label: Text('1')),
            ],
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
          ),
          Builder(builder: (content) {
            switch (_selectedIndex) {
              case 0:
                return TestContent(key: PageStorageKey('TestContent')); // assign a unique key
              default:
                return Container();
            }
          }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestContent extends StatefulWidget {
  TestContent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestContentState createState() => _TestContentState();
}
class _TestContentState extends State<TestContent> {
  String _text = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _text = PageStorage.of(context)?.readState(context) as String? ?? '';
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    PageStorage.of(context)?.writeState(context, _text); // save the state
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Expanded(
        child: TextFormField(
          initialValue: _text,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _text = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```